Accessing menus in telnet suddenly very slow
screenshotI am new to this type of programming so please bare with me.  Client PCs login via putty using SSH and the user's bash profile is used to take them to a menu screen like the attached pic being hosted by a Centos server.  Until very recently, moving between menus was lightning fast.  Today, the time it takes to load a new menu from the previous is 150 seconds.  I have a backup server with the menus replicated and they operate very quickly compared to the production server.  My gut instinct is that this is a DNS problem but any feedback and guidance is much appreciated.
Thanks
Mike
I have confirmed that the webserver on this same server is functioning properly.
All devices on the network seem to be functioning properly from a DNS standpoint.
